# bind_rows() with id column as the variable name of the data.frame

Tags: r

The `.id` argument `dplyr::bind_rows()` can help distinguish between two `union`ed `data.frames`.  However, instead of the numerical `id`s it produces, I would like to show the names of the `data.frame`s in that column.  How can I do that?

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <-
  data.frame(
    x = c(1,2,3),
    y = c(4,5,6)
  )

df2 <-
  data.frame(
    x = c(7,8,9),
    y = c(10,11,12)
  )

bind_rows(df1, df2, .id = 'source')
#>   source x  y
#> 1      1 1  4
#> 2      1 2  5
#> 3      1 3  6
#> 4      2 7 10
#> 5      2 8 11
#> 6      2 9 12
```

Expected output

```r
#>   source x  y
#> 1    df1 1  4
#> 2    df1 2  5
#> 3    df1 3  6
#> 4    df2 7 10
#> 5    df2 8 11
#> 6    df2 9 12
```

Comment: If you read the `dplyr` documentation, you can assign the source column based on a named list `bind_rows(list(df1=df1, df2=df2), .id= 'id')`. Or you could just create a source column before calling `bind_rows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this approach

```
# Create a list of data frames
df_list <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)

# Use bind_rows with .id argument
result <- bind_rows(df_list, .id = "source")

# Print the result
print(result)
```

Output:

```
     source x  y
1    df1 1  4
2    df1 2  5
3    df1 3  6
4    df2 7 10
5    df2 8 11
6    df2 9 12
```